# Even with Less Secure Apps ON, we cannot authenticate to R's googlesheets library

Tags: r, authentication, google-sheets

We are running `googlesheets::gs_auth(new_user = TRUE)` from RStudio, which prompts us to select an email address:

[image]

.

.
.
.
We select the relevant email address and we get to here:

[image]

.

.
.
.
we confirm that Less Secure Apps is toggled On for this account. Note that we just toggled it On a few minutes ago.

[image]

Is there something else we need to do to authenticate? Clear some cookies? Perhaps just wait 24 hours? Here is a related thread - [Unable to authenticate googlesheets package for R studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114277/unable-to-authenticate-googlesheets-package-for-r-studio) - however the solution requires making the google sheet public, which we must avoid. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check out the [info on the package repo](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets) you'll see that the API that the package used is no longer available.

> googlesheets is going away fairly soon (in 2020)! It is not a good idea to write new code that uses it!
>
> googlesheets (this package) wraps the Sheets v3 API, which is quite old and is gradually going offline, starting in March 2020. Full shutdown is planned for September 2020. When that happens, this R package will be of no use and will presumably be archived on CRAN in due course.

You should use the [googlesheets4](https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/) package instead.

Comment: Ahh good find. I will give other library a try and see if i have more success.